# How to customize the footer container in magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, footer

I want to remove the footer container add new customize footer! I already remove the footer links but the (Enter your email address | Subscribe) and the white background is still there!

I want to remove them all and add new custom footer!

Comment: I want to remove the footer container

Comment: @PiepPiper, check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove using that code:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
```

Or you can customize your footer from this file:

> app/design/frontend/[Package]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml

```
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer">
        //Add your custom footer HTML and CSS
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way that i can add mine without editing the xml code?

Comment: @PiepPiper or if you want to hide then you can hide it by css display:none;

Comment: I mean that i want to add a new footer!

Comment: @PiepPiper I have update my answer for add custom html in footer.

Comment: Should i put it in (Miscellaneous HTML)?

Comment: @PiepPiper, yes you can and check if it will work as per your requirement then you can do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78621/discussion-between-pieppiper-and-nikunj-vadariya).

Answer (score 3):

**Try this code :**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
      <referenceBlock name="footer.container" remove="true" />
  </body> 
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code in layout XML (default.xml of your theme).

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

> app/design/frontend/[Package]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
      <referenceBlock name="footer.container" remove="true" />
  </body> 
</page>
```

**OR**

**Without XML:-**

```
.page-footer {
    display: none;
}
```